# Android disable fullscreen activity

Tags: android

The problem I'm having is only on devices running KitKat and I believe it's because of the [immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html).

Basically its this:

At some point in my app, I can click on a picture. This triggers the following code.

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivityForResult(intent, 99);
```

I can now select one of the installed apps that are registered for handling images. Selecting, for example, the gallery app, the image is opened but the gallery is is fullscreen. The problem is that at the same time I can receive notifications that are shown in the status bar. In KitKat the user, when seeing the image in the external app, misses those notifications. This is only happening on KitKat.

Can I force the gallery app to open not in fullscreen or is any possible way of the notifications been shown?

Comment: You can not change other apps. If the gallery app your user chooses hides the system bars, it's up to the user and the gallery app. In KitKat, the user can swipe down from the top of the screen to show the notifications bar. An alternative you can try is have an activity from your app to show the images.